# error in deployment of ML model with AWS elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**getting this error while deployemnt**

Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-05421752a11f59b8e'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-05421752a11f59b8e] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.. Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed. Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.

just try to deploy but getting this error , dont know what to do next